# Is there a way to make an autocomplete in 2 fields where the first change the possible values in the second? (JS, SQL and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, jquery-ui

I made an autocomplete using jquery where the first field is required in a SQL (SSMS) table and are different trucks manufacturers, I need the second field to be just that manufacturers' models but can't figure out how i could do that. :(
Here's part of my HTML:

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <label>Marca<input type="text" id="marca" name="marca" placeholder="Write the truck manufacturer"
        required /></label>
</div>
<div style="width:500px;">
    <label>Modelo<input type="text" id="modelo" name="modelo" placeholder="Write the truck model"
    required /></label>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("search.php", function(data){
    var item_callback = [];
    $(data).each(function(key,value){
        item_callback.push(value.CAM_FABRN);
    })
    $("#marca").autocomplete({
        source: item_callback
    });
});
</script>
```

Part of the php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "connection.php";
$fabricantes = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT CAM_FABRN 
                                FROM CAM010 
                                WHERE CAM_DTE >='2018'");
$fabricantes->execute();
echo json_encode($fabricantes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

connection.php is:

```
<?php 
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=(local) ; Database = Portal_Registro ", "", "", array(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => true));
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and also provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you really connecting to an SQLServer with no username or password

Comment: I think you need a `;` after `Database = Portal_Registro`

Comment: You can set the proper `source` for the Autocomplete and it will call the PHP as you like. Your PHP Script should accept a `term` and then use that in the SQL Query to filter the results down.